# How to resolve the "EVP_DecryptFInal_ex: bad decrypt" during file decryption

Tags: c, encryption, openssl

I have the following query.Could any one please suggest me a solution.

I'm working on encryption and decryption of file for first time.

I have encrypted file through command prompt using the command:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in file.txt -out file.enc -k "key value" -iv "iv value"
```

I have to decrypt it programmatically. So I have written the program for it, but it is throwing the following error:

```
./exe_file enc_file_directory
...
error: 06065064: digital envelope routines: EVP_DecryptFInal_ex: bad decrypt: evp_enc.c
```

---

The program below takes input as directory path and search for encrypted file ".enc" and try to decrypt it read into buffer.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#include <libxml/globals.h>

void handleErrors(char *msg)
{
    {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        printf("%s", msg);
        abort(); 
    }
}

void freeMemory(char *mem)
{
    if (NULL != mem)
    {
        free(mem);
        mem = NULL;
    }
}

/* Function to decrypt the XML files */

int decryptXML(unsigned char *indata, unsigned char *outdata, int fsize)
{

    int outlen1 = 0, outlen2 = 0;

    unsigned char iv[] = "b63e541bc9ece19a1339df4f8720dcc3";
    unsigned char ckey[] = "70bbc518c57acca2c2001694648c40ddaf19e3b4fe1376ad656de8887a0a5ec2" ;

    if (NULL == indata)
    {
        printf ("input data is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (0 >= fsize)
    {
        printf ("file size is zero\n");
        return 0;
    }

    outdata = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char) * fsize * 2);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);

    if (! EVP_DecryptInit_ex (&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, ckey, iv))
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    handleErrors("DInit");
    }

    if (! EVP_DecryptUpdate (&ctx, outdata, &outlen1, indata, fsize))
    {
        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        handleErrors("DUpdate");
    }

    if (! EVP_DecryptFinal_ex (&ctx, outdata + outlen1, &outlen2))
    {

        EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
        handleErrors("DFinal");
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

    return outlen1+outlen2;

}

int isDirectory(char *path)
{
    DIR *dir = NULL;
    FILE *fin = NULL, *fout = NULL;
    int enc_len = 0, dec_len = 0, fsize = 0, ksize = 0;
    unsigned char *indata = NULL, *outdata = NULL;
    char buff[BUFFER_SIZE], file_path[BUFFER_SIZE], cur_dir[BUFFER_SIZE];

    struct dirent *in_dir;
    struct stat s;

    if (NULL == (dir = opendir(path)))
    {
        printf ("ERROR: Failed to open the directory %s\n", path);
        perror("cannot open.");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (NULL != (in_dir = readdir(dir)))
    {

        if (!strcmp (in_dir->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(in_dir->d_name, ".."))
            continue;

        sprintf (buff, "%s/%s", path, in_dir->d_name);

        if (-1 == stat(buff, &s))
        {
            perror("stat");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (S_ISDIR(s.st_mode))
        {

            isDirectory(buff);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(file_path, buff);

            if (strstr(file_path, ".enc"))
            {

                /* File to be decrypted */

                fout = fopen(file_path,"rb"); 

                fseek (fout, 0L, SEEK_END);
                fsize = ftell(fout);
                fseek (fout, 0L, SEEK_SET);

                indata = (char*)malloc(fsize);

                fread (indata, sizeof(char), fsize, fout);

                if (NULL == fout)
                {
                    perror("Cannot open enc file: ");
                    return 1;
                }


                dec_len = decryptXML (indata, outdata, fsize);
                outdata[dec_len] = '\0';
                printf ("%s\n", outdata);
                fclose (fin);
                fclose (fout);

            }
        }
    }



    closedir(dir);
    freeMemory(outdata);
    freeMemory(indata);

    return 1; 
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int result;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf ("Usage: <executable> path_of_the_files\n");
        return -1;
    }

    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OPENSSL_config(NULL);

    /* Checking for the directory existance */

    result = isDirectory(argv[1]);

    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();

    if (0 == result)
        return 1;
    else
       return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: CBC mode provides confidentiality only, and you usually must add a MAC to use CBC mode safely. You should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Simplify your code. Do away with all the file system reading. Encrypt one file and try to decrypt that file. Debugging is much easier then.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Did you mean that use of system calls from the program ?

Answer (score 186):

This message `digital envelope routines: EVP_DecryptFInal_ex: bad decrypt` can also occur when you encrypt and decrypt with an incompatible versions of openssl.

The issue I was having was that I was encrypting on Windows which had version 1.1.0 and then decrypting on a generic Linux system which had 1.0.2g.

It is not a very helpful error message!

---

## Working solution:

A possible solution from @AndrewSavinykh that worked for many (see the comments):

> Default digest has changed between those versions from md5 to sha256. One can specify the default digest on the command line as `-md sha256` or `-md md5` respectively

Comment: See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39641378/284111 Default digest has changed between those versions from md5 to sha256. One can specify the default digest on the command line as `-md sha256` or `-md md5` respectively

Comment: I just upgraded from Kubuntu artful to Kubuntu bionic which updated openssl from 1.0.2g to 1.1.0g and I was unable to decrypt some files. The default hash used by `openssl enc` for password-based key derivation changed in 1.1.0 to SHA256 versus MD5 in lower versions ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/344586)). My solution was to [download the older `openssl` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/openssl), force install it with `dpkg`, decrypt the file(s), force update the `openssl` package from the repository (using Synaptic for instance) and encrypt the files again.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh please put your comment as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh pls post it as an answer. because it is

Comment: How to specify this in the C API?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Anyway it must be said - people from openssl are complete bumpkins. This is not a toy program, it's not a calculator or some game, seriously ... People like myself have important stuff encrypted with this program. Financial and legal stuff! So when I suddenly need document encrypted couple years ago and instead of document, or at least info "use openssl with version X to decrypt" I get some stupid "bad decrypt" message it's like heart attack.

Comment: @LLL The [man page for `openssl enc`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html) specifically states "For bulk encryption of data, whether using authenticated encryption modes or other modes, cms(1) is recommended, as it provides a standard data format and performs the needed key/iv/nonce management."  [The license](https://www.openssl.org/source/license-openssl-ssleay.txt): "THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED ... "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED."

Comment: (cont) You called OpenSSL's maintainers "bumpkins" because ***you*** misused a convenience tool that stores data in some unknown, undocumented format, with zero warranty, and with documented security deficiencies to protect your important data.

Comment: Thankyou very much. This helped me recover a very old encrypted file.

Comment: thanks man!!! I never ever could describe it better than LLL did. LOL

for me at the end -md md5 helped. 
again thanks!!! and @LLL  : you made my day :)))

Answer (score 19):

I experienced a similar error reply while using the openssl command line interface, while having the correct binary key (-K). The option  "-nopad" resolved the issue:

Example generating the error:

```
echo -ne "\x32\xc8\xde\x5c\x68\x19\x7e\x53\xa5\x75\xe1\x76\x1d\x20\x16\xb2\x72\xd8\x40\x87\x25\xb3\x71\x21\x89\xf6\xca\x46\x9f\xd0\x0d\x08\x65\x49\x23\x30\x1f\xe0\x38\x48\x70\xdb\x3b\xa8\x56\xb5\x4a\xc6\x09\x9e\x6c\x31\xce\x60\xee\xa2\x58\x72\xf6\xb5\x74\xa8\x9d\x0c" | openssl aes-128-cbc -d -K 31323334353637383930313233343536 -iv 79169625096006022424242424242424 | od -t x1
```

Result:

```
bad decrypt
140181876450560:error:06065064:digital envelope 
routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:535:
0000000 2f 2f 07 02 54 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 29 00 00
0000020 00 00 04 a9 ff 01 00 00 00 00 04 a9 ff 02 00 00
0000040 00 00 04 a9 ff 03 00 00 00 00 0d 79 0a 30 36 38
```

Example with correct result:

```
echo -ne "\x32\xc8\xde\x5c\x68\x19\x7e\x53\xa5\x75\xe1\x76\x1d\x20\x16\xb2\x72\xd8\x40\x87\x25\xb3\x71\x21\x89\xf6\xca\x46\x9f\xd0\x0d\x08\x65\x49\x23\x30\x1f\xe0\x38\x48\x70\xdb\x3b\xa8\x56\xb5\x4a\xc6\x09\x9e\x6c\x31\xce\x60\xee\xa2\x58\x72\xf6\xb5\x74\xa8\x9d\x0c" | openssl aes-128-cbc -d -K 31323334353637383930313233343536 -iv 79169625096006022424242424242424 -nopad | od -t x1
```

Result:

```
0000000 2f 2f 07 02 54 0b 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 29 00 00
0000020 00 00 04 a9 ff 01 00 00 00 00 04 a9 ff 02 00 00
0000040 00 00 04 a9 ff 03 00 00 00 00 0d 79 0a 30 36 38
0000060 30 30 30 34 31 33 31 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f 2f
0000100
```

Answer (score 14):

I think the Key and IV used for encryption using command line and decryption using your program are not same.

Please note that when you use the "-k" (different from "-K"), the input given is considered as a password from which the key is derived. Generally in this case, there is no need for the "-iv" option as both key and password will be derived from the input given with "-k" option.

It is not clear from your question, how you are ensuring that the Key and IV are same between encryption and decryption.

In my suggestion, better use "-K" and "-iv" option to explicitly specify the Key and IV during encryption and use the same for decryption. If you need to use "-k", then use the "-p" option to print the key and iv used for encryption and use the same in your decryption program.

More details can be obtained at https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/enc.html

Comment: Thank you Jay. yeah! you were right it was not getting the correct key and iv value. it tried a simple program with your suggestion (using -K, -iv and -p options) and it worked.

I have another query here.

I have generated an private key using this command
**openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048**

I have encrypted a file using this key as below
**openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in rand_bytes.c -out rand_bytes.enc -kfile key.pem**

Now the question is,
I have to read the same key to decrypt the file using OpenSSL EVP API's.

Could you suggest me, how it can be achieved. 

Thank you.

Comment: @Sai: If this answered your particular question, please mark it as the answer for this thread. The other answer is helpful for a different reason, but by marking this as the answer to your specific problem, it clarifies that this thread is not a duplicate of the one linked on the other answer.

Answer (score 9):

Errors:
"Bad encrypt / decrypt"
"gitencrypt_smudge: FAILURE: openssl error decrypting file"

There are various error strings that are thrown from openssl, depending on respective versions, and scenarios. Below is the checklist I use in case of openssl related issues:

1. Ideally, openssl is able to encrypt/decrypt using same key (+ salt) & enc algo only.
2. Ensure that openssl versions (used to encrypt/decrypt), are compatible. For eg. the hash used in openssl changed at version 1.1.0 from MD5 to SHA256. This produces a different key from the same password.
   Fix: 
   add "-md md5" in 1.1.0 to decrypt data from lower versions, and 
   add "-md sha256 in lower versions to decrypt data from 1.1.0
3. Ensure that there is a single openssl version installed in your machine. In case there are multiple versions installed simultaneously (in my machine, these were installed :- 'LibreSSL 2.6.5' and 'openssl 1.1.1d'), make the sure that only the desired one appears in your PATH variable.

Comment: What is the equivalent to specify in the C API?

Answer (score 8):

This message can also occur when you specify the **incorrect decryption password** (yeah, lame, but not quite obvious to realize this from the error message, huh?).

I was using the command line to decrypt the recent DataBase backup for my auxiliary tool and suddenly faced this issue.

Finally, after 10 mins of grief and plus reading through this question/answers I have remembered that the password is different and everything worked just fine with the correct password.

Comment: This was my case. Wrong password!

Comment: This is my case too! Definitely should be the FIRST thing one verifies for this issue!

Answer (score 7):

You should use decrypted private key. For example: `youprivatekey.decrypted.key`. You can run this command to decrypt your private key file.

```
openssl rsa -in <encrypted_private.key> -out <decrypted_private.key>

Enter password:

Enter pass phrase for encrypted_private.key: <enter the password>

Wait:

writing RSA key

it's done...
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me! Had an error code "1C800064" in nodejs to enable ssl cert.

Answer (score 4):

My case, the server was encrypting with padding disabled. But the client was trying to decrypt with the padding enabled.

While using EVP_CIPHER*, by default the padding is enabled. To disable explicitly we need to do

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(context, 0);
```

So non matching padding options can be one reason.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error trying to do a chain encrypt decrypt encrypt with DES in ECB mode. Turning off padding fixed the problem.