# Getting an error when trying to decrypt file using openssl

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to use openssl to encrypt a private key that I later need to decrypt to use as part of a JWT auth workflow.

The steps to generate the key are below:

```
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out server.pass.key 2048
$ openssl rsa -passin pass:x -in server.pass.key -out server.key
$ rm server.pass.key
$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key - 
out server.crt
$ rm server.csr
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -k $KEY -in assets/server.key -out 
assets/server.key.enc -e
```

the $KEY is a symmetric password I've saved to my bash instance. When I try to decrypt I get this error:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -k $KEY -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -d -md sha256

bad decrypt
4736276076:error:06FFF064:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad 
decrypt:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl- 
22.240.1/libressl-2.6/crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:533:
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATH had an outdated version of OPENSSL. Referred to this article to set the PATH correctly 
[Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/update-openssl-on-os-x-with-homebrew)

Comment: Also this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304570/how-to-resolve-the-evp-decryptfinal-ex-bad-decrypt-during-file-decryption