# Heroku production server encryption and local decryption fail

Tags: node.js, heroku, encryption

I am encrypting some text with the following `encrypt` function on Heroku:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

// function to encrypt data ....
function encrypt(KEY, text){
  const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', KEY);
  var encrypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8', 'hex');
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return encrypted;
}

// function to decryt data..............
function decrypt(KEY, text){ 
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes192', KEY) 
    var decrypted = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8') 
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8'); 
    return decrypted; 
 }
```

It then saves the text I encrypted to MongoDb server. I read the encrypted value and try to decrypt it on the local machine, but get a `digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`. I have spent so much time trying to figure out what is the issue.

Both in Heroku and locally I am using the same key. If I try this code locally (i.e. encrypt and decrypt locally), then everything works as expected.

Do you have an idea of what might be going wrong?

I have noticed that heroku server is in United States, while I am in UK. Does the timezone play any role in here?

Comment: there are lot of factors that are mentioned in this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304570/how-to-resolve-the-evp-decryptfinal-ex-bad-decrypt-during-file-decryption

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve the "EVP\_DecryptFInal\_ex: bad decrypt" during file decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304570/how-to-resolve-the-evp-decryptfinal-ex-bad-decrypt-during-file-decryption)

Comment: thanks for this. my local openssl is 1.1.1b. checking the heroku version

Comment: yup. it is older. thank you!