# Error: Job failed: exit code 1 - bad decrypt

Tags: openssl, continuous-integration, gitlab, salesforce, continuous-deployment

I'm at Step 4 of Review the Pipeline section of module "Package your App and Automate CI/CD" of "Build an Automated CI/CD Pipeline with GitLab" trailhead and see "Error: Job failed: exit code 1.  I would like to resolve this issue.  (got my 100 points as I continued anyway from here) Would like to see test run PASS per the trailhead.

I'm continuing on with module 6 and need my tests to PASS first otherwise, I'm blocked.

Anyone with suggestion(s)?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Tien 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304570/how-to-resolve-the-evp-decryptfinal-ex-bad-decrypt-during-file-decryption

Comment: Thank you, @NicolasPepinster.  Hope that this will help me resolve my issue.

Comment: still stumped.  Tried all kinds of suggestions from more learnings and research from readings, i.e., 
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -md md5 -in assets/server.key.enc -out assets/server.key -K $SERVER_KEY_PASSWORD -iv 0 -p
Extra arguments given.
aes-256-cbc: Use -help for summary

but still no progress (Error: Job failed: exit code 1).   Help!