# Decrypt a text with OpenSSL using key and salt only

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes, lets-encrypt

I would like to decrypt a text using a 32 characters key and a salt from command line in my MacOS. I have encrypted it in Windows using a program. But, whenever I try to decrypt it from command line I couldn't and get an error.

```
echo -n PuYNZO+SLqFo6g97gxKr2uAPRUph/sZgaJ3T5YIBPIc= | openssl enc -d -a -aes-256-cbc -K TheTestKeyUsedIs32CharactersLong -S 53616c7455736564 -iv 0 -p
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
hex string is too short, padding with zero bytes to length
non-hex digit
invalid hex key value
```

When I try to encrypt

> 100836

in MacOS it gives me completely different string.

> U2FsdGVkX19TYWx0VXNlZA4AWDWo5nzi8p5pYyAeUMg=

using following command:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -S 53616c7455736564 -iter 5 -k TheTestKeyUsedIs32CharactersLong -in input.txt -out openssl_output.txt
```

From the application I am using in Windows

> 100836
>   is converting into 
>   PuYNZO+SLqFo6g97gxKr2uAPRUph/sZgaJ3T5YIBPIc=

- My salt text is **SaltUsed**
- My 32 bit character key is **TheTestKeyUsedIs32CharactersLong**
- Input is **PuYNZO+SLqFo6g97gxKr2uAPRUph/sZgaJ3T5YIBPIc=**
- Should be decrypted in **100836**

But, result is completely unexpected.

I have also tried a java program to decrypt it but there I was getting other strings so thought to correct it with command line first and then will jump into the code.

I also tried the key in hex digits but still the response was incorrect and was not as expected.

Comment: Please note you provided the salt as 8 bytes hex encoded value. I believe the key needs to be hex encoded too

Comment: I tried that too and with that the encrypted text was U2FsdGVkX19TYWx0VXNlZFhz3AhDtVqRkFhh/MKT6Pg=

Comment: hey, are you using a '0' IV when encrypting?

Comment: Yes, as I am not defining any Index Vector

Comment: ok, pls give me the full command you encrypt with on windows

Comment: openssl  aes-256-cbc -a -S 53616c7455736564 -k 546865546573744b65795573656449733332436861726163746572734c6f6e67 -in input.txt -out output.txt 
In input.txt I have 100836

Comment: ok I get "U2FsdGVkX19TYWx0VXNlZAD3LdGa6jcowV4IArNB0PY=" when I encrypt input.txt with 100836 inside on macOS with that command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206839/discussion-between-woodstock-and-wasif-kirmani).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Wasif and I spent some time debugging in chat and in the end believe it's most likely a compatbility issue between `OpenSSL 1.1.1.d` on Windows and `OpenSSL 1.1.1.b` on macOS.

We went through a number of tests and permutations, using `(Key, IV)` tuples in hex, using passwords, with and without salts, and ultimately our testing came down to a simple check.

Using `openssl enc -a -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:MYPASSWORD -p -in input.txt` on Windows we got:

```
salt=E70092FEBA619144 
key=29631452F8C259DFE6FD8E9372EC4B20392395F36B7A0B11769CEBEA987E90A0 
iv =93BF2E94462A43B23EF585C0F4B3F1A8 
U2FsdGVkX1/nAJL+umGRRGi3ybIPFXf7qrgov7SyXnI=
```

Using `openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -pass pass:MYPASSWORD -in cipherText.txt (which contains 'U2FsdGVkX1/nAJL+umGRRGi3ybIPFXf7qrgov7SyXnI='` on the Mac we got:

```
4593573484:error:06FFF064:digital envelope routines:CRYPTO_internal:bad decrypt
```

Despite this simple test failing, the Mac and Windows boxes successfully encrypted and decrypted locally.

**Weird, but this looks like version incompatibility.**

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the digest alorithm:

Default digest has changed between different versions.

See
[How to resolve the "EVP_DecryptFInal_ex: bad decrypt" during file decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304570/how-to-resolve-the-evp-decryptfinal-ex-bad-decrypt-during-file-decryption)